# Python Script for fetching files Gives error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'remote_path' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

The script I use below to fetch files created yesterday. I get the error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'remote_path' referenced before assignment"

Here is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import paramiko
import fnmatch
import os
import glob
from stat import S_ISDIR
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

paramiko.util.log_to_file('logfileIN.log')

host = "xx.xx.xx.xx"
port = 22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
password = "password"
username = "username"
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

local_dir = '/home/inbox/ZTEIN/'
remote_dir = '/data/REFA/coll/directory/remote/'

yesterday = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y%m%d")
cdrfile= '*'+ str(yesterday)+'*.r'

def serv_dir(remote_dir, local_dir):
        os.path.exists(local_dir) or os.makedirs(local_dir)
        rm_dir = sftp.listdir_attr(remote_dir)
        for item in rm_dir:
                # assuming the local system is Windows and the remote system is Linux
                # os.path.join won't help here, so construct remote_path manually
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(item.filename, cdrfile):
                        remote_path = remote_dir + '/' + item.filename
                        local_path = os.path.join(local_dir, item.filename)
                if S_ISDIR(item.st_mode):
                        serv_dir(remote_path, local_path)
                else:
                        sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)


serv_dir("/data/REFA/coll/data_c/DWH_ZTEIN/","/home/inbox/ZTEIN/")

sftp.close()
transport.close()
```

Where could the error be on the script?

Comment: When you enter the `for` loop, `remote_pat` and `local_path` are only set if `fnmatch.fnmatch` finds a match, but the `if S_ISDIR(item.st_mode)` block is executed whether or not `fnmatch.fnmatch` finds a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(item.filename, cdrfile):
                    remote_path = remote_dir + '/' + item.filename
                    local_path = os.path.join(local_dir, item.filename)
            else: #added
                    remote_path = ... # added
                    local_path = ... # added

            if S_ISDIR(item.st_mode):
                    serv_dir(remote_path, local_path)
            else:
                    sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if fnmatch.fnmatch(item.filename, cdrfile):
    remote_path = remote_dir + '/' + item.filename
    local_path = os.path.join(local_dir, item.filename)
```

When this `if` statement is false, `remote_path` is not defined.  So, it must be false.